# How to replace text and punctuation

Tags: r

How do you replace text and punctuation?

```
X = "Ann + Sam + Bob + Jan"
Y <- gsub (" + Sam","",X)
```

Comment: I would advise to learn regular expressions (e.g. start by typing ?regex). It's an extremely powerful way to deal with character strings. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set `fixed = T` because `+` is a special regex character.

```r
X = "Ann + Sam + Bob + Jan"
Y <- gsub(" + Sam", "", X, fixed=T)
```

As a rule of thumb whenever you're not using regular expressions it's better to set the `fixed` flag to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Or another option is to escape (`\\` the `+`

```
gsub("\\s*\\+\\s*Sam", "", X)
```

#### data

```
X = "Ann + Sam + Bob + Jan"
```